# What happens when you don't get a proper answer, or no answer at all?

Tags: discussion, questions, accept-rate

I would like to know what will happen to my reputation and accept rate when:

#### I asked a question and:

1. I didn't get a proper answer (so I can't accept one).
2. I'm not getting any replies at all. Same question.
3. I have found the answer myself later.

How will it affect my reputation and accept rate?
What is the standard procedure to close the question in the last scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, as the FAQ points out, answering your own question is fine, but you will not receive 15 rep for accepting your own answer. It will, however, positively impact your accept rate.

Effect on rep: You don't get +2 for accepting. Effect on accepted %: It will not be 100%, and may decrease. However, if there is no good answer to accept, then its impact on your accepted % will be unavoidable; for this reason, I feel that accepted % is not very important.

Comment: Hi @Can't Get Enough Mahna, thanks for the answer :D

Comment: As for "no answer at all", the question will never affect your accept rate if the question has no answers yet.

Comment: @animuson That is correct.

Comment: @sameera207 Thanks for the accept!